# Install Section of rpm package

Tags: linux, rpm, rpm-spec

I am naive on creating RPM packages.

I want to know the meaning of below command:

```
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/build-%{name}-%{version}

      %install
      rm -rf "%{buildroot}"
      install -m 0755 -d "%{buildroot}%{_prefix}"
       %__install -D -m0644 "%{SOURCE0}" "%{buildroot}%{_prefix}/ROOT.war"

%files
%dir %{_prefix}
%{_prefix}/ROOT.war
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the `%install` section, you are supposed to install all your files in the `%{buildroot]` directory; just the way they will be installed on the final system.

```
rm -rf "%{buildroot}"
```

he cleans this directory. I never use this; since my buildroot is unique for each of my packages. (using `BuildRoot:  %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-build` in the beginning of my spec file)

```
install -m 0755 -d "%{buildroot}%{_prefix}"
```

there seems to have been a `%{_prefix}` variable declared; he just creates that directory. Probably `%{_prefix}` is reused in the `%files` section then.

```
%__install -D -m0644 "%{SOURCE0}" "%{buildroot}%{_prefix}/ROOT.war"
```

here the file `%{SOURCE0}` is installed (copied) to the `%{buildroot}%{_prefix}` directory. So in the %files section I would expect a line like this:

```
%files
%{_prefix}/ROOT.war
```

meaning that the ROOT.war file is to be packaged in that rpm.

**EDIT**
the `%__install -D` command just expands to `/usr/bin/install -D` (see [defined macros](http://rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/config_macros.html))

the `-D` option is explained in the install man page:

> -D
>   create all leading components of DEST except the last, then copy SOURCE to DEST

Comment: Thanks a lot! But, what this %__install -D  does ?